# bash - extract part of variable that starts with digit

Tags: bash

I have the following variable 'VAR1' in a bash script:

```
VAR1 = "/path/to/file/190909_AAA_ZZZ/"
```

I now want to create a variable (VAR2) that only contains the part "190909".

I want to do this by extracting the part that starts with any 6 digits (190909) until the next "_"

How can this be achieved?

```
VAR2 = ${grep ... $VAR1} ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `sed` command:

```
var1="/path/to/file/190909_AAA_ZZZ/"
var2=$(sed -E 's~.*/([0-9]{6})_.*~\1~' <<< "$var1")
echo "$var2"
```

```
190909
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `.*/`: Match anything (greedy) till we match `/`
- `([0-9]{6})`: Match 6 digits and capture it in group #1
- `_.*`: Match `_` and everything until end

Replacement is `\1` which is to put captured group #1 value back.

Answer (score 5):

Please try the following:

```
VAR1="/path/to/file/190909_AAA_ZZZ/"
[[ $VAR1 =~ ([0-9]{6})_ ]] && VAR2=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo "$VAR2"
```

Output:

```
190909
```

Note that it is not recommended to use uppercase letters for normal variable names.

Answer (score 0):

pcre grep and perl equivalents:

```
$ VAR1="/path/to/file/190909_AAA_ZZZ/"
$ grep -oP '[0-9]{6}(?=_)' <<< $VAR1
190909
$ perl -nE 'say for /([0-9]{6}(?=_))/' <<< $VAR1
190909
```

Explanation on regex: https://regex101.com/r/D2NVOl/1